# Apache 2.4.6 and Apache Tomcat 7.0.42 on Port 80

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, mod-jk, ubuntu-13.10

On my Ubuntu 13.10 I have installed Apache and Tomcat. I am trying to get tomcat to work on port 80 with no luck at all. I have looked at using mod_jk following several online tutorials with no success. What I am trying to achieve is I have a webapp on tomcat running as the root application. Therefore the current url is www.example.com:8080. I also have apache which is on the url www.example.com. I want to be able to access files on the apache webserver for e.g www.example.com/somefile but also have my webapp running at the sametime on www.example.com. Please can anyone help.

Comment: You need to add url redirection to apache and check for the path in apache httpd.conf.

Check the path of the incoming request is just example.com then you rewrite it to example.com:8080.

Comment: What modules would i need to do this and what files would I have to alter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this problem by Using Mod_Proxy. Editing the 000-Deafult.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and adding the following lines:

```
ProxyPass /SomeUrl !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
```

The first line indicates what you don't want to proxy and the second one indicates what to proxy.In this case forward the ROOT app of Tomcat at port 8080 to the root of the Apache web server

Also edited the server.xml file in /etc/tomcat7 and added the following

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="AJP/1.3" proxyName="www.mydomain.com" proxyPort="80"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add url redirection to apache and check for the path in apache httpd.conf.

Check the path of the incoming request is just example.com then you rewrite it to example.com:8080.

The mod_proxy of apache should be able to do this for you.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/proxy-howto.html

Comment: According to those instructions i went and changed my server.xml to include: <Connector port="8081" protocol="AJP/1.3" proxyName="www.mysite.com" proxyPort="80"/> and also changed my httpd.conf to contain: 

ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8081/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8081/

Its not working can someone please show an example of what Im trying to to do

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat by default runs on port 8080. Incase if you need to run it in port 80 you need to use [JSVC](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) which comes along with tomcat. If you have installed tomcat by downloading the binary version then jsvc will be available under

```
[tomcat_install_path]/bin/commons-daemon-native.tar.gz
```

you need to untar it and compile it. Compiling it is easy.

```
# ./configure
# make
```

once you have compiled it you will get the jsvc binary file which needs to be placed under the tomcat bin directory.

Then to start up tomcat with the help of jsvc follow the steps mentioned [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html#Unix_daemon)

JSVC is the officially recommended way of starting Tomcat in port 80.